# JSON conversion error csv

Tags: python

I have below JSON format  and I want to convert that into CSV file.
This data is basically the stock position. I want to download the
position  every 5 min..and close position if required. I downloaded the json data but unable to convert into csv

```
'net':[  
  {  
     'tradingsymbol':'IDBI',
     'exchange':'NSE',
     'instrument_token':377857,
     'product':'BO',
     'quantity':0,
     'overnight_quantity':0,
     'multiplier':1,
     'average_price':0,
     'close_price':0,
     'last_price':57.8,
     'value':-15.75,
     'pnl':-15.75,
     'm2m':-15.75,
     'unrealised':-15.75,
     'realised':0,
     'buy_quantity':35,
     'buy_price':57.5,
     'buy_value':2012.5,
     'buy_m2m':2012.5,
     'sell_quantity':35,
     'sell_price':57.05,
     'sell_value':1996.75,
     'sell_m2m':1996.75,
     'day_buy_quantity':35,
     'day_buy_price':57.5,
     'day_buy_value':2012.5,
     'day_sell_quantity':35,
     'day_sell_price':57.05,
     'day_sell_value':1996.75
  }    ],    'day':[  
  {  
     'tradingsymbol':'IDBI',
     'exchange':'NSE',
     'instrument_token':377857,
     'product':'BO',
     'quantity':0,
     'overnight_quantity':0,
     'multiplier':1,
     'average_price':0,
     'close_price':0,
     'last_price':57.8,
     'value':-15.75,
     'pnl':-15.75,
     'm2m':-15.75,
     'unrealised':-15.75,
     'realised':0,
     'buy_quantity':35,
     'buy_price':57.5,
     'buy_value':2012.5,
     'buy_m2m':2012.5,
     'sell_quantity':35,
     'sell_price':57.05,
     'sell_value':1996.75,
     'sell_m2m':1996.75,
     'day_buy_quantity':35,
     'day_buy_price':57.5,
     'day_buy_value':2012.5,
     'day_sell_quantity':35,
     'day_sell_price':57.05,
     'day_sell_value':1996.75
  }    ] } emp_data = employee_parsed['data']
print(emp_data)    
employ_data = open('C:/watch/Position.csv', 'w',newline='')
print(employ_data)
csvwriter = csv.writer(employ_data)
count = 0
for emp in emp_data:    
      if count == 0:    
             header = emp.keys()    
             csvwriter.writerow(header)    
             count += 1    
      csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())    
employ_data.close()
```

Getting this error at this line

```
header = emp.keys()
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Any solution please.

Comment: what information does Position.csv contain? is it a csv file or a json?

Comment: also check 'json' module for reading the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your are having a JSON string

Try:

```
import json
emp_data = json.loads(employee_parsed['data'])
```